# Can I bind mouse wheel scroll to jump?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, mouse

I've been playing GoldSrc and Source games a decent bit, and for them use the scroll wheel for jumping. Is there is a way to set mouse wheel up and down to jump in Minecraft Java Edition?

Mods or anything
Any way

Comment: There's no official way to do so but there may be mods for it. However, I suggest just getting used to using other controls if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using X Mouse Button Control

This is an application that basically lets you do anything with your mouse. Although if misused, it can be considered as a macro on multiplayer servers, which may get you banned so *use it at your own risk.* The app itself is safe to use and is Legit.

**How the method works :-**
We are going to use an application that allows you to bind your mouse buttons so that they perform functions of other keys. The idea is to set your scroll up to a button that you do not use usually in game. Then to go in game and set jump to that key. For example you can set your mouse scroll up to Insert and set Insert as the Jump button in game.

1. Download the application [here](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm).
2. On opening the app you will see this :[image]
3. Make sure your Minecraft is running when you do this. After opening mc, go to xmouse app and click on 'add'[image]
4. On doing so It will ask you to choose an applications among the running applications. Select minecraft. After doing so, perform the following steps (I did not add minecraft as a profile).
   If you do not add minecraft as a profile then changing your scroll wheel's function will change it always, but if you add an application, then the changes will work only when you are in the application, In this case, minecraft.
5. Now, go to 'Wheel up' and select the drop down menu.
6. Click on "Simulated Keys"[image]
7. On doing so, you will be able to see the following screen. [image]
8. Select the drop down menu that looks like this [image]
9. Go to standard keys and select any one which you usually never use in game. For example, Select Insert.[image]
10. Click on Ok and then apply.

After doing this whenever you open your game, your scroll wheel up will behave as if you were pressing the insert key. Finally, go to controls in the game and set Jump to Insert and your task is done.